# Как проверить с помощью SQL-запроса что поле имеет заданное округление?

Tags: sql, тестирование

Каким запросом проверить, что значения в столбце округлены, например, до 3-х знаков после запятой ? Или Обратный запрос, что нет значений, отличных от трёхзнакового округления.

Comment: А как Вы округлять будете?

Comment: @V.March  Не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос. Я тестирую доработку и один из пунктов - это проверка округления. Слабо представляю как с помощью запроса можно распарсить строку и  посчитать символы после запятой.

Comment: У Вас проблема с тем узнать есть ли сам факт округления, или получить эту строку, и распарсить строку,  и посчитать символы после запятой? Как минимум начните с того как Вы можете получать с этой базы данные. Потом в каком виде они могут к Вам придти.   И определитесь как вы будете оценивать резльтат. Вы ожидаете в результате запроса к базе ответ "значение было округлено" или просто набор данных с которыми Вы потом будте работать? Если первый вариант - то узнайте хранит ли база информацию что значение округлялось  или Может ли база сама округлять поступающие к ней данные.

Comment: @V.March данные в БД поступают из SAP. Есть некоторая новая функциональность, которая пересчитывает один из столбцов таблицы. Мой вопрос в том, как я могу убедиться на выгрузке, например, в 100 000 строк, что все значения в вычисляемом столбце имеют вид ...,000

Comment: Значить Вам нужно парсить и анализировать Выгрузку а не делать запрос к базе?

Comment: Или все же проверять есть ли функция округления в базе? Для этого варианта Вам Akina предложил отличный готовый запрос. Он Вам подходит?

Comment: Какое отношение к вопросу имеет метка plsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> проверить с помощью SQL-запроса что поле имеет заданное округление

Если имеется в виду поле таблицы, то

```
SELECT column_name, 
       data_type, 
       numeric_precision, 
       numeric_scale 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'database'
  AND table_name = 'table'
  AND data_type IN ('decimal','float','double');
```

Если речь о поле в некоем наборе данных - то в общем случае никак.

> как с помощью запроса можно распарсить строку и посчитать символы после запятой

```
(LOCATE(SUBSTRING(1.1 FROM 2 FOR 1), field) > 0) * LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, SUBSTRING(1.1 FROM 2 FOR 1), -1))
```

Если убеждён, что фортелей с десятичным разделителем не предвидится, то просто

```
(LOCATE('.', field) > 0) * LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '.', -1))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! Без лишних умствований и по делу. Вы мне очень помогли